# jquery proper chaining?

Tags: jquery, chaining

I have the following:

```
$("#modal-controls").html(html)
  .find("#pic_caption").val(data.pic_caption)
  .find("#pic_desc").val(data.pic_desc);
```

Basically, I change the html of something, search for inputs and change their values.
it changes the 1st one, but doesn't proceed to change the 2nd input, How will I go about writing it properly using chaining? or must I seperate it to 2 different jQuery objects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`jQuery.fn.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/). You can add it to the chain to revert back to the previous set of matched elements.

```
$("#modal-controls").html(html)
  .find("#pic_caption").val(data.pic_caption).end() //<--
  .find("#pic_desc").val(data.pic_desc);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is because the first `find()` places the current chain at `#pic_caption`. Use [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) to return to the previous selector chain, eg

```
$("#modal-controls").html(html)
  .find("#pic_caption").val(data.pic_caption).end()
  .find("#pic_desc").val(data.pic_desc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your HTML structure is like this:

```
<div id="modal-controls">
    <input type="button" id="pic_caption" value="">
    <input type="button" id="pic_desc" value="">
</div>
```

You need to use jQuery `end()` ([DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/end/)) to return the filter to the original selector for the chained `find()`:

```
$("#modal-controls").html(html)
  .find("#pic_caption").val(data.pic_caption)
  .end()
  .find("#pic_desc").val(data.pic_desc);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your selector is not looping through the matches, it is only hitting the first one.  Try this one assuming you have multiple modal-controls...

```
$("#modal-controls").each(function(index){
  $(this).html(html)
  .find("#pic_caption").val(data.pic_caption)
  .find("#pic_desc").val(data.pic_desc);
});
```